# MS Access Double click on Listbox run time error 3075

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a listbox that is bound to a table (tblTransferDetail).  The Primary Key is 'TransNum' (type INT) and the listbox is bound to this as the first column.

The double click event of the listbox (lstScannedItems) executes the below code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblTransferDetail WHERE TransNum = " & Me.lstScannedItems, dbSeeChanges
```

However, when I double click on a record in the listbox I keep receiving 'VBA Runtime error 3075' and the above line is highlighted.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: while in debug mode, what does `Me.lstScannedItems` evaluate to ? (just hover over it)

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: `Debug.Print "DELETE FROM tblTransferDetail WHERE TransNum = " & Me.lstScannedItems` to see the query string. You can see what wrong with the query.

Comment: In Debug it evaluates to NULL - why is this?

Comment: You may consider adding a `*` and try - `DELETE * FROM tblTransferDetail WHERE TransNum = " & Me.lstScannedItems`

Comment: We can't tell you why something evaluates to null without knowing how it's set up. Is that box multiselect? Because then you might need to iterate `.SelectedItems`

Comment: @Vityata - tried added * but receive runtime error 3075 stll

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It is multi selected - added .SelectedItems but receive error 'Method or data member not found'

Comment: @Michael Oh, silly, it's `ItemsSelected`, I've added an answer on how to use that.

Comment: Just a note, using DoubleClick event on a multi-select listbox is a weird user interface, that will probably not work as you want.

Comment: @Andre ok thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply iterate through `.ItemsSelected` and then execute the query with the itemdata for each selected item.

```
Dim v As Variant
For Each v In Me.lstScannedItems.ItemsSelected
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblTransferDetail WHERE TransNum = " & Me.lstScannedItems.ItemData(v)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

`Me.lstScannedItems` will work only when the value is bound column. if you need to use the selection and then go through the selection collection to find out which one is selected.

```
Dim opValue As String
Dim x As Long
With Me.lstScannedItems
    For x = 0 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(x) = True Then
            opValue = .List(x)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
End With
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblTransferDetail WHERE TransNum = " & opValue, dbSeeChanges
```

Comment: I amended the above to 'opValue = Me.lstScannedItems(x)' but now I receive the type mistmatch error and this line is highlighted.  TransNum is long integer.

Comment: It should be `Me.lstScannedItems.List(x)`.